# Maven is not creating a project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to create a java maven project from Eclipse. While trying to create a project i am getting an error

> "Could not resolve archetype"

Below is the screenshot of the error. If anyone could assist me please let me know.

```
Could not resolve archetype org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp:2.27 from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp:jar:2.27
Failure to transfer org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp:jar:2.27 from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jersey-quickstart-webapp-repo has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp:jar:2.27 from/to jersey-quickstart-webapp-repo (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Failed to transfer
```

Answer (score 0):

try to click the create a simple project (skip archetype selection) box when creating